# How to set custom IPrinciple for service bus worker threads

Tags: nservicebus

I have my own IPrinciple and IIdentity implementation. How can I configure Generic Host to have specific IPrinciple in Thread.CurrentPrinciple in handler implementation?

Comment: Can you add some context about what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to authorize the handling of certain messages?

Comment: I implemented own IPrinciple and IIdentity which is used across all application and I use that via Thread.CurrenctPrincipal ie. during saving data to database to fill fields like ModifiedBy. I have created special user for NServiceBus Host, which I want to setup on application start.

Answer (score 0):

Since the NSB host runs as a Windows service, I don't think you can override it globally.  I'm thinking you need to just use the WindowsImpersonationContext class to impersonate using your Identity.  Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/autz_auth_stuff/archive/2011/05/14/windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx)